# Correct format for DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have the below string which I need to parse to a DateTime:

```
Thu Aug 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

I am unsure what format to supply to my `DateTime.ParseExact` to achieve this. The nearest I could find in standard date/time format string was Full date/time pattern (long time) as below but this does not work

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Thu Aug 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (GMT Summer Time)", "F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // FormatException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give examples from other time zones as well? (I'm sure you'll have to do some string manipulation first.) Do you care about the time zone offset, or do you *just* want the local time?

Comment: I only have an example in GMT. Local time is fine thanks, offset is not important. Not sure if the info is relevant but the date string is being passed from a KendoUI Grid dataItem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the offset is not important, I suggest you just truncate the string after the time.

It looks like the format should allow that by finding the first space after position 16 (the start of the time in your example; part way through the time if the day number is shorter):

```
int endOfTime = text.IndexOf(' ', 16);
if (endOfTime == -1)
{
    throw new FormatException("Unexpected date/time format");
} 
text = text.Substring(0, endOfTime);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(I'm assuming the month and day names are *always* in English.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, works great as long as I take the HH:mm:ss off the format string in your answer

Comment: @Jimsan: Don't do that - instead, change the index. I've fixed my answer now - basically I had miscounted before.

Comment: Does C# not have a way to parse timezone?

Comment: @jjxtra: Not built into DateTime.Parse etc, no.

Comment: I was able to use this format string to parse out a numberic time zone using DateTime.ParseExact, but I guess the generic DateTime.Parse call cannot do this, at least from my initial observations : `dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzzz` For a string like `02/Mar/2020:12:13:14 -0400`

Comment: @jjxtra: That's not a time zone, that's a UTC offset. I'd expect `DateTime.Parse` to be able to handle that too, but it's probably best to use `ParseExact` anyway. Or better, frankly, would be to use my Noda Time project, but that's a slightly different matter...

Comment: Right. Yes I agree your libraries have more robust parsing functionality :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain it will always be GMT summer time, couldn´t you use this:

```
var str = "Mon Jan 05 1987 07:45:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Summer Time)";
var f = "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'K' (GMT Summer Time)'";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or if summer/winter can change but always GMT, regardless of offset.

```
var str = "Mon Jan 05 1987 07:45:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Summer Time)".Split('(')[0].Trim();
var f = "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'K";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```